# ngCordova : $cordovaFileTransfer upload image and transfer text to server

Tags: php, angularjs, cordova-plugins, ngcordova

I am using $cordovaFileTransfer to upload picture, audio ,video and PDF file from my Ionic Application to PHP server. I successfully upload picture but failed to upload video, audio and pdf file to server.

Next, I also could not pass other parameter to my PHP server.

The following is my code.

Front-end Code

```
   function onSuccess(imageData) {
                    var url = "http://131.4.44.69/php2/attachment.php";
                    var options = {
                        fileKey: "file",
                        chunkedMode: false,
                        mimeType: "multipart/form-data",
                        params : {
                            "usernames": usernames,
                            "usernameID" : usernameID,
                            "subscribeChannel" : subscribeChannel,
                            "channelID" : channelID,
                            "attachment" : attachment
                        }
                    };

                    $cordovaFileTransfer.upload(url, imageData, options).then(function(result) {
                        alert('Image Successfully uploaded');
                    },function(err){
                        alert(err);
                    });
```

Back-end Code

```
<?php
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

    $imageName = date("d.m.Y H:i:s");
    $imageName = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $imageName);
    $imageName = str_replace(',', '', $imageName);
    $imageName = str_replace(':', '', $imageName);

    $file_ext=strtolower(end(explode('.',$_FILES['file']['name'])));
    $usernames = $_FILES['file']['usernames'];
    $usernameID = $_FILES['file']['usernameID'];
    $subscribeChannel = $_FILES['file']['subscribeChannel'];
    $channelID = $_FILES['file']['channelID'];
    $attachment = $_FILES['file']['attachment'];

    $target_path = 'image_attachment' . '/' . $imageName .  '.'. $file_ext ;


    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
        echo "Upload and move success";
    } else{
        echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
    }
?>
```